# UITableViewCell: understanding life cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have got a ViewController with a UITableView containing custom UITableViewCell subclasses.

The project I am working on is based on a Master/Detail view controller template (the one from XCode 6).

Things I noticed:

- when I go back to the Master view the **dealloc method** of the cell is **not called**
- when I go from master to detail view (where the table is) the awake from nib method is called and then the dealloc method as well. I don't get this. Why would the dealloc method be called after the awake from nib?

This is the current life cycle as I observed it:

- Once the table reload method is called it triggers awake from nib of the custom cell and then the dealloc method is called (why not before?)

I added an NSLog on both methods of the subclass of UITableViewCell to observe this.

**EDIT:** my problem is that I have a UISlider in the custom cell. When the dealloc get called the updated slider value is there (E.g. say 10) but on the UI it does show the initial value set via interface builder (e.g. say 1). I assume that the default values are set again (restored) after dealloc is called. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: When you go from master to detail then first awakefromnib call and after dealloc method call of mastervc.this happens because if dealloc call first then it release all object then how can get detailvc's object and property..

Comment: my problem is that I have a UISlider in the custom cell. When the dealloc get called the updated slider value is there (E.g. say 10) but on the UI it does show the initial value set via interface builder (e.g. say 1). I assume that the default values are set again (restored) after dealloc is called. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Base the data in your views off of your model values.... hence MVC. This is how you keep your views in sync with your data. You ViewController should be setting up these initial values and configuring the cells with data from your data source. If you follow that flow, the issues you are seeing should go away.

Comment: Which method do I need to call in order to set the initial values and configuring the cells with the data from my data source correctly?

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is not normal. You should see dealloc of the cell when you go back to the master, and you shouldn't see any dealloc when you go forward. How are you going back to the master?

Comment: Yes I am going back to the master view.. I am a bit lost.

Comment: Initial values for the cell should be set in cell for row at index path, prepare for reuse, and awake from nib. Between all of these, you should be treating a cell at a reusable component that needs it's state reset when dequeued.

Answer (score 0):

The way UIKit handles dealloc is totally opaque; I doubt you will find many people who have seen its implementation and would be willing to show it to you. Because we don't have a good way to know what exactly's going on under the hood, it's tough to tell if what you're seeing is normal behavior or something strange. That being said, there are methods you can use to configure the cell as it is about to be displayed to set the value of the slider appropriately. The best way, in my experience, would be to set that slider's value in cellForRowAtIndexPath. After your tableViewController calls dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath, expose a method on your UITableViewCell subclass to set the value of the slider according to your data source. If, after setting the slider's value here, it is still defaulting to the value on your storyboard, then something is definitely not working as expected and we'll need to see more code to figure out where it's going wrong.