# Custom UITableViewCell, UISlider subview unexpected sizing behavior

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, awakefromnib

I have a UISlider in a custom UITableViewCell.
When I look at the size of the slider in `awakeFromNib` the `.frame` property shows the size of the slider as it was set in the storyboard, not the final size as it is drawn when the view appears.

I had thought all of that set up was done in `awakeFromNib` but the size of the slider seems to change between awakeFromNib and its final appearance.

I found a similar question from 2015 that had an answer posted but was not actually resolved.

[UITableViewCell: understanding life cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493984/uitableviewcell-understanding-life-cycle)

I also found a similar question from 2016, but that one doesn't seem to apply to my situation.

[Swift UITableViewCell Subview Layout Updating Delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318582/swift-uitableviewcell-subview-layout-updating-delayed)

I have added a screen capture of my constraints as set in the storyboard.

[image: UISlider constraints]

Comment: So what is the current issue? Is the width/height slider incorrect?

Comment: The width is incorrect. When I look at the .frame.width in awakeFromNib it shows the value as set in the storyboard, not the width after it is presented. So the issue I'm having is that I am calculating the position of other interface elements based on the slider's size. So after the view is presented those other elements shift, as the size of the slider has changed.

Comment: Did you run on the same device or simulator in the storyboard? Specifically, iPhone 15 Pro in this scenario. Can you show the actual screenshots of this issue?

Comment: When I run it on the iPhone 15 simulator the size of the slider is correct (as set in storyboard). When run on iPhone 15 Pro the size in awakeFromNib shows as the size set in storyboard, then, when the view presents, the slider size looks correct and the width reads as correct for iPhone 15 Pro. (I hope this makes sense.)  So I don't think that showing a screen shot will be helpful, since by the time the view is presented the slider is the correct size.

Comment: It's true, because you're using autolayout, that means your layout can be changed with its superView. In `viewDidLoad` or `awakeFromNib`, it just gets the interface file (which is from .xib or storyboard file), then adjusts with superView. You can print out both on viewDidLoad/awakeFromNib and viewDidLayoutSubviews/layoutSubviews to see differents

Comment: I see. So to get the behavior I'm looking for – getting the final size of the slider before it is first displayed – I should not use auto layout for the slider and instead set the slider size programmatically in awakeFromNib?

Comment: I think if you want a fixed size for this, you can use both autolayout or frame with auto-resizing. However, it should be handled from superView. For example: get `IBOutlet` for the width constraint, then modify later. In my opinion, I think it's weird because making it fit with ratio of each screen is the best choice instead of a fixed size.

Comment: @psb - what are you doing that you need to calculate *"the position of other interface elements based on the slider's size"*? The common approach is to setup the constraints of the UI elements so they adapt to the view (in your case, the table view cell) at run-time.

Comment: The slider represents a timeline. The user can place two markers (UILabels) on that time line ("start time" and "finish time" for example). So the relative position of "9am" will be different based on the size of the device. I'm calculating where on the timeline the markers should be positioned.

Comment: @psb - are you trying to set the x-position of the little up-arrows?

Comment: @DonMag - Yes, correct! (I have been offline for a while.)
I am able to do it, however when the TableViewCell is first presented the markers are displayed in a position relative to the size of slider as set in the storyboard, then they jump to the correct position (for the larger device).
I can try to add more detail to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know the size of the cell (and its UI components) until `layoutSubviews()`

So, assuming you are setting the arrow positions as percentages, implement `layoutSubviews()` in your cell class along these lines:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    // the thumb "circle" extends to the bounds / frame of the slider
    // so, this is how we get the
    //  thumb center-to-center
    //  when value is 0 or 1.0
    let trackRect = theSlider.trackRect(forBounds: theSlider.bounds)
    let thumbRect = theSlider.thumbRect(forBounds: theSlider.bounds, trackRect: trackRect, value: 0.0)
    let rangeWidth = theSlider.bounds.width - thumbRect.width
    
    // Zero will be 1/2 of the width of the thumbRect
    //  minus 2 (because the thumb image is slightly offset from the thumb rect)
    let xOffset = (thumbRect.width * 0.5) - 2.0
    
    // create the arrow constraints if needed
    if startConstraint == nil {
        startConstraint = startArrow.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.leadingAnchor)
        startConstraint.isActive = true
    }
    if endConstraint == nil {
        endConstraint = endArrow.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.leadingAnchor)
        endConstraint.isActive = true
    }
    
    // set arrow constraint constants
    startConstraint.constant = rangeWidth * startTime + xOffset
    endConstraint.constant = rangeWidth * endTime + xOffset
}
```

I'm assuming all of your rows will have the same "time range" for the slider, so we can get something like this (I set the thumb tint to translucent and the arrow y-positions so we can see the alignment):

[image]

For a complete example (to produce that output), use this Storyboard https://pastebin.com/nUZFMtGN (had to move it since this answer became too long) - and this code:

```
class SliderCell: UITableViewCell {
    // startTime and endTime are in Percentages
    public var startTime: Double = 0.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var endTime: Double = 0.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    @IBOutlet var startArrow: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var endArrow: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var startEndLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var minLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var maxLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var theSlider: UISlider!
    
    private var startConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var endConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // the thumb "circle" extends to the bounds / frame of the slider
        // so, this is how we get the
        //  thumb center-to-center
        //  when value is 0 or 1.0
        let trackRect = theSlider.trackRect(forBounds: theSlider.bounds)
        let thumbRect = theSlider.thumbRect(forBounds: theSlider.bounds, trackRect: trackRect, value: 0.0)
        let rangeWidth = theSlider.bounds.width - thumbRect.width
        
        // Zero will be 1/2 of the width of the thumbRect
        //  minus 2 (because the thumb image is slightly offset from the thumb rect)
        let xOffset = (thumbRect.width * 0.5) - 2.0
        
        // create the arrow constraints if needed
        if startConstraint == nil {
            startConstraint = startArrow.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.leadingAnchor)
            startConstraint.isActive = true
        }
        if endConstraint == nil {
            endConstraint = endArrow.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.leadingAnchor)
            endConstraint.isActive = true
        }
        
        // set arrow constraint constants
        startConstraint.constant = rangeWidth * startTime + xOffset
        endConstraint.constant = rangeWidth * endTime + xOffset
    }
}

struct MyTimeInfo {
    var startTime: Date = Date()
    var endTime: Date = Date()
}

class SliderTableVC: UITableViewController {
    
    var myData: [MyTimeInfo] = []
    
    var minTime: Double = 0
    var maxTime: Double = 24

    var minTimeStr: String = ""
    var maxTimeStr: String = ""
    
    var timeRange: Double = 24
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // let's generate some sample data
        let starts: [Double] = [
            8, 7, 11, 10.5, 8.25, 9,
        ]
        let ends: [Double] = [
            20, 23, 19, 16.5, 21.75, 21,
        ]
        let y = 2023
        let m = 11
        var d = 1
        for (s, e) in zip(starts, ends) {
            var dateComponents = DateComponents()
            dateComponents.year = y
            dateComponents.month = m
            dateComponents.day = d
            dateComponents.hour = Int(s)
            dateComponents.minute = Int((s - Double(Int(s))) * 60.0)
            let sDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
            dateComponents.hour = Int(e)
            dateComponents.minute = Int((e - Double(Int(e))) * 60.0)
            let eDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
            myData.append(MyTimeInfo(startTime: sDate, endTime: eDate))
            d += 1
        }
        
        minTime = starts.min() ?? 0
        maxTime = ends.max() ?? 24
        timeRange = maxTime - minTime
        
        minTimeStr = timeStringFromDouble(minTime)
        maxTimeStr = timeStringFromDouble(maxTime)
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sliderCell", for: indexPath) as! SliderCell
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        var h = calendar.component(.hour, from: myData[indexPath.row].startTime)
        var m = calendar.component(.minute, from: myData[indexPath.row].startTime)

        let s: Double = Double(h) + Double(m) / 60.0

        h = calendar.component(.hour, from: myData[indexPath.row].endTime)
        m = calendar.component(.minute, from: myData[indexPath.row].endTime)
        
        let e: Double = Double(h) + Double(m) / 60.0
        
        let sPct: Double = (s - minTime) / timeRange
        let ePct: Double = (e - minTime) / timeRange
        
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.timeStyle = .short

        let sStr = df.string(from: myData[indexPath.row].startTime)
        let eStr = df.string(from: myData[indexPath.row].endTime)

        df.dateStyle = .short
        df.timeStyle = .none
        
        c.dateLabel.text = df.string(from: myData[indexPath.row].startTime)
        
        c.startTime = max(sPct, 0.0)
        c.endTime = min(ePct, 1.0)
        
        c.startEndLabel.text = sStr + " - " + eStr
        
        c.minLabel.text = minTimeStr
        c.maxLabel.text = maxTimeStr
        
        return c
        
    }
    func timeStringFromDouble(_ t: Double) -> String {
        
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.timeStyle = .short
        
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = Int(t)
        dateComponents.minute = Int((t - Double(Int(t))) * 60.0)
        
        var date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
        return df.string(from: date)

    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

If we want, we can get rid of the position calculations in `layoutSubviews()` altogether...

Let's start with a custom slider thumb image, which we can generate at run-time using an SF Symbol - the background will be clear:

[image] [image]

If we use that with `.setThumbImage(arrowThumb, for: [])`, it will look like this (I've given it a translucent background for clarity):

[image]

Now we could, for example, set the slider's:

```
.minimumValue = 7.0   // (hours - 7:00 am)
.maximumValue = 23.0  // (hours - 11:00 pm)
```

and then set the value to the time.

So, we can use one for the "start time" and overlay another one for the "end time":

[image]

If we then set:

```
.setMinimumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: [])
.setMaximumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: [])
```

on both sliders, we get this:

[image]

We'll set `.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` for both of those sliders, and overlay an interactive slider on top:

[image]

Debug View Hierarchy:

[image]

When we remove the translucent background:

[image]

At this point, we no longer need to do anything in `layoutSubviews()` ... we just set the `.value` of the "startMarkerSlider" and the "endMarkerSlider" and the arrow-markers will be automatically positioned.

[image]

Here's example code for that approach - all code, no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections...

```
// convenience extension to manage Date Times as fractions
// for example
//  convert from to 10:15 to 10.25
// and
//  convert from 10.25 to 10:15
extension Date {
    var fractionalTime: Double {
        get {
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let h = calendar.component(.hour, from: self)
            let m = calendar.component(.minute, from: self)
            return Double(h) + Double(m) / 60.0
        }
        set {
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: self)
            components.hour = Int(newValue)
            components.minute = Int(newValue * 60.0) % 60
            self = calendar.date(from: components)!
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Table View Cell class**

```
class AnotherSliderCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    public var sliderClosure: ((UITableViewCell, Double) -> ())?
    
    private var minTime: Date = Date() { didSet {
        startMarkerSlider.minimumValue = Float(minTime.fractionalTime)
        endMarkerSlider.minimumValue = startMarkerSlider.minimumValue
        theSlider.minimumValue = startMarkerSlider.minimumValue
    }}
    private var maxTime: Date = Date() { didSet {
        startMarkerSlider.maximumValue = Float(maxTime.fractionalTime)
        endMarkerSlider.maximumValue = startMarkerSlider.maximumValue
        theSlider.maximumValue = startMarkerSlider.maximumValue
    }}
    private var startTime: Date = Date() { didSet {
        startMarkerSlider.setValue(Float(startTime.fractionalTime), animated: false)
    }}
    private var endTime: Date = Date() { didSet {
        endMarkerSlider.setValue(Float(endTime.fractionalTime), animated: false)
    }}
    private var selectedTime: Date = Date() { didSet {
        theSlider.setValue(Float(selectedTime.fractionalTime), animated: false)
    }}

    private let theSlider = UISlider()
    private let startMarkerSlider = UISlider()
    private let endMarkerSlider = UISlider()
    
    private let infoLabel = UILabel()
    private let minLabel = UILabel()
    private let maxLabel = UILabel()
    private let selLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        [endMarkerSlider, startMarkerSlider, theSlider, infoLabel, minLabel, maxLabel, selLabel].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            theSlider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 6.0),
            theSlider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theSlider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            minLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            minLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            minLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            maxLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: minLabel.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            maxLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            maxLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            selLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: minLabel.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            selLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // constrain sliders to overlay each other
        [endMarkerSlider, startMarkerSlider].forEach { v in
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSlider.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])
        }

        var arrowThumb: UIImage!

        // if we can get the "arrowshape.up" SF Symbol (iOS 17 or custom), use it
        //  else
        // if we can get the "arrowshape.left" SF Symbol, rotate and use it
        //  else
        // use a bezier path to draw the arrow
        if let sfArrow = UIImage(systemName: "arrowshape.up") {
            
            let newSize: CGSize = .init(width: 31.0, height: (sfArrow.size.height * 2.0) + 3.0)
            let xOff = (newSize.width - sfArrow.size.width) * 0.5
            let yOff = (newSize.height - sfArrow.size.height)
            
            arrowThumb = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:newSize).image { renderer in
                // during development, if we want to see the thumb image framing
                //UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.25).setFill()
                //renderer.cgContext.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
                sfArrow.draw(at: .init(x: xOff, y: yOff))
            }
            
        } else if let sfArrow = UIImage(systemName: "arrowshape.left") {
            
            let sizeOfImage = sfArrow.size
            var newSize = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: sizeOfImage).applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi * 0.5)).size
            
            // Trim off the extremely small float value to prevent core graphics from rounding it up
            newSize.width = floor(newSize.width)
            newSize.height = floor(newSize.height)
            
            let rotArrow = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:newSize).image { renderer in
                //rotate from center
                renderer.cgContext.translateBy(x: newSize.width/2, y: newSize.height/2)
                renderer.cgContext.rotate(by: .pi * 0.5)
                sfArrow.draw(at: .init(x: -newSize.height / 2, y: -newSize.width / 2))
            }
            
            newSize = .init(width: 31.0, height: (rotArrow.size.height * 2.0) + 3.0)
            var xOff: CGFloat = (newSize.width - rotArrow.size.width) * 0.5
            var yOff: CGFloat = newSize.height - rotArrow.size.height
            
            arrowThumb = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:newSize).image { renderer in
                // during development, if we want to see the thumb image framing
                //UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.25).setFill()
                //renderer.cgContext.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
                rotArrow.draw(at: .init(x: xOff, y: yOff))
            }
            
        } else {

            let vr: CGRect = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 31.0, height: 40.0)
            let r: CGRect = .init(x: 6.5, y: 23.0, width: 18.0, height: 16.0)
            
            var pt: CGPoint = .zero
            let pth = UIBezierPath()
            
            pt.x = r.midX - 3.0
            pt.y = r.maxY
            pth.move(to: pt)
            pt.y = r.maxY - 8.0
            pth.addLine(to: pt)
            pt.x = r.minX
            pth.addLine(to: pt)
            pt.x = r.midX
            pt.y = r.minY
            pth.addLine(to: pt)
            pt.x = r.maxX
            pt.y = r.maxY - 8.0
            pth.addLine(to: pt)
            pt.x = r.midX + 3.0
            pth.addLine(to: pt)
            pt.y = r.maxY
            pth.addLine(to: pt)
            pth.close()
            
            arrowThumb = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: vr.size).image { ctx in
                
                ctx.cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
                
                ctx.cgContext.setLineWidth(1)
                ctx.cgContext.setLineJoin(.round)
                
                ctx.cgContext.addPath(pth.cgPath)
                ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .stroke)
                
            }
            
        }
        
        [endMarkerSlider, startMarkerSlider].forEach { v in
            v.setThumbImage(arrowThumb, for: [])
            v.setMinimumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: [])
            v.setMaximumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: [])
            v.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }

        infoLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .regular)
        infoLabel.textAlignment = .center
        infoLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        
        minLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .light)
        maxLabel.font = minLabel.font

        selLabel.font = minLabel.font
        selLabel.textColor = .systemRed

        theSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        theSlider.thumbTintColor = .green.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
    }
    
    @objc func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        
        df.dateStyle = .none
        df.timeStyle = .short
        
        var dt = Date()
        dt.fractionalTime = Double(sender.value)
        selLabel.text = "Thumb Time: " + df.string(from: dt)

        sliderClosure?(self, Double(sender.value))
    }
    
    public func fillData(minTime: Date, maxTime: Date, mti: MyTimeInfo) {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        
        df.dateStyle = .full
        df.timeStyle = .none
        
        let part1: String = df.string(from: mti.startTime)

        df.dateStyle = .none
        df.timeStyle = .short
        
        let startStr: String = df.string(from: mti.startTime)
        let endStr: String   = df.string(from: mti.endTime)
        let selStr: String   = df.string(from: mti.selectedTime)

        let minStr: String = df.string(from: minTime)
        let maxStr: String = df.string(from: maxTime)

        infoLabel.text = part1 + "\n" + "Marker Times" + "\n" + startStr + " - " + endStr
        minLabel.text = minStr
        maxLabel.text = maxStr
        selLabel.text = "Thumb Time: " + selStr
        
        self.minTime = minTime
        self.maxTime = maxTime
        self.startTime = mti.startTime
        self.endTime = mti.endTime
        self.selectedTime = mti.selectedTime
    }
    
    // we don't need layoutSubviews() anymore
    //override func layoutSubviews() {
    //  super.layoutSubviews()
    //}
    
}
```

---

**Example controller class**

```
class AnotherSliderTableVC: UITableViewController {
    
    var myData: [MyTimeInfo] = []
    
    var minTime: Date = Date()
    var maxTime: Date = Date()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        // let's generate some sample data
        let samples: [[String]] = [
            ["11/2/2023 9:00 AM", "11/2/2023 9:00 PM"],
            ["11/2/2023 9:00 AM", "11/2/2023 5:00 PM"],
            ["11/3/2023 10:00 AM", "11/3/2023 5:00 PM"],
            ["11/4/2023 10:20 AM", "11/4/2023 2:45 PM"],
            ["11/5/2023 9:15 AM", "11/5/2023 9:30 PM"],
            ["11/6/2023 11:00 AM", "11/6/2023 6:00 PM"],
            ["11/7/2023 11:45 AM", "11/7/2023 7:30 PM"],
            ["11/8/2023 10:45 AM", "11/8/2023 4:00 PM"],
            ["11/9/2023 8:35 AM", "11/9/2023 9:00 PM"],
        ]
        
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"
        
        samples.forEach { ss in
            if let st = df.date(from: ss[0]),
               let et = df.date(from: ss[1]) {
                var selt = st
                // init with 12:00 as selectedTime for all samples
                selt.fractionalTime = 12.0
                let mt = MyTimeInfo(startTime: st, endTime: et, selectedTime: selt)
                myData.append(mt)
            }
        }
        
        // let's use these min/max times for the sliders
        //  the Date will be ignored ... only the Time will be used
        var sTmp = "11/2/2023 7:00 AM"
        if let d = df.date(from: sTmp) {
            minTime = d
        }
        sTmp = "11/2/2023 11:00 PM"
        if let d = df.date(from: sTmp) {
            maxTime = d
        }
        
        tableView.register(AnotherSliderCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ac")
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cc = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ac", for: indexPath) as! AnotherSliderCell
        cc.fillData(minTime: minTime, maxTime: maxTime, mti: myData[indexPath.row])
        cc.sliderClosure = { [weak self] theCell, theValue in
            guard let self = self,
                  let idx = tableView.indexPath(for: theCell)
            else { return }
            self.myData[idx.row].selectedTime.fractionalTime = theValue
        }
        return cc
    }
    func timeStringFromDouble(_ t: Double) -> String {
        
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.timeStyle = .short
        
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = Int(t)
        dateComponents.minute = Int((t - Double(Int(t))) * 60.0)
        
        let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
        return df.string(from: date)
        
    }
}
```

---

Note that I also changed the approach to using the data, so we're dealing directly with `Date` objects.

Comment: I truly appreciate your detailed and thorough answer!
I sort of solved my issue, in as much as I did figure out a solution (albeit one that isn't as robust as yours, and also includes a little visual "hiccup" when the view appears.)
I will definitely comb your approach and modify my solution.
Thank you!

Comment: Due to some feature changes to my app I redesigned it such that I removed the labels in storyboard, instead adding them (along with other visual elements) programmatically. Your solution led me to the understanding that I needed to move much of the subviews location calculations to layoutSubviews() (... calling setNeedsLayout() where necessary.) Everything now works as I had expected.
Again, very much appreciated.

Comment: @psb - if you're interested, I added an **Edit** to my answer with another approach that ***I*** would find easier to manage.